# How to convert lat long in CSV to decimal format in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a csv that contains multiple columns like:

```
id, latitude,longitude
1, 20-55-70.010N,32-11-50.000W
2, ..., ...
```

Assuming I have a CSV file that contains many of these, how could I effectively output a CSV that contains all the latitude longitude converted to decimal using pig while preserving all other columns?

Comment: what is your desired output will look like?

Comment: Desired output is still a CSV, but the latitude and longitude columns should be in decimal format as opposed to the string.

Comment: i.e. 20.55.70.010N,32.11.50.000W?

Comment: Decimal numbers only, no N or W, expecting a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write [a PIG UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/udf.html) to convert from geographic coordinates (DMS) to decimal degrees.
See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) explaining how to perform the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete just the N and the W you can use Substring function.

```
SUBSTRING(latitude,0,12) , SUBSTRING(longitude,0,12)
```